# ggplot2: geom_point() dodge shape but NOT color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get a plot in ggplot2 with geom_point() having variables mapped to x, y, color and shape and to dodge the position for color but not shape.

```
x=tibble(Color=c(rep('A',12),rep('B',12),rep('C',12)),
     Shape=rep(c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3),rep('C',3),rep('D',3)),3),
     xVar=rep(c('A','B','C'),12),
     Value=rnorm(36))

ggplot(x,aes(xVar,Value,color=Color,shape=Shape))+
     geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.5))
```

Is it possible to restrict the dodge position to just one aesthetic? I've scoured documentation and stack overflow but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: How about `ggplot(data=x) + geom_point(aes(xVar, Value, color=Color), position=position_dodge(width=.5)) + geom_point(aes(xVar,Value,shape=Shape))`

Comment: I don't see any other option than duplicate the points as juan proposed. How can you have the shape of a point at a position, and the color at another?

Comment: @PaulEndymion, no need for duplication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `group` determines dodging, so one can do:

```
ggplot(x, aes(xVar, Value, color = Color, shape = Shape, group = Shape))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I guess I didn't get the question in the first place.