# ggplot2: Is there a way to eliminate distortions of shapes when using geom_point and position_dodge?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making plots that have categorical x variables with multiple factors for each category. I use geom_point and position_dodge similar to this post: [ggplot2: geom_point() dodge shape but NOT color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169234/ggplot2-geom-point-dodge-shape-but-not-color). If you look closely at the plot created in that post you can see that when xVar=C the "+" points are not symetrical, in that the right and bottom lines are longer than the top and left. Perhaps this is not a big deal for simple plots, but I have a fairly complex plot. I have a 3*3 multi-plot using grid_arrange. This multi-plot has a total of 81 points and error bars for each of the points. The distorted points are not centered on many of the error bars, so this problem really stands out in my case. Perhaps this has something to do with using position_dodge with grid_arrange.

I've tried exporting the image as different file types (e.g., jpg, png, pdf).

Here is some code from the aforementioned link:

```
x=tibble(Color=c(rep('A',12),rep('B',12),rep('C',12)),
     Shape=rep(c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3),rep('C',3),rep('D',3)),3),
     xVar=rep(c('A','B','C'),12),
     Value=rnorm(36))

ggplot(x,aes(xVar,Value,color=Color,shape=Shape))+
     geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.5))

ggplot(x,aes(xVar,Value,color=Color,shape=Shape,group=Shape))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.5))
```

I would like to have geom_point shapes that are not distorted.

Comment: The "asymmetric '+' legs" are due to saving it to the file, not due to `ggplot2`. When I rendered the other question to PDF, all pluses are perfect. So I think this is an issue of image dimensions and resolution (DPI). (You said you saved to PDF ... how did you do it? When exported via vector-methods (vice raster), it should be symmetric.

Comment: I used the export tab in rStudio. Here's a link to an image of my pdf multi plot: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/wa1O1lA.jpg). The squares are still distorted.